# My code doesn't seem to perfect (changing a word with a subword)

Tags: c

Hello guys i got this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main () {
  int length;
  char strin[100],*p,*p1;
  gets(strin);
  length= strlen(strin);
  do {
        p = strstr(strin," HEY ");
        if (p != NULL) {
            for (p1=strin+length-1;p1>=p+4;p1--)
             *(p1+1) = *(p1);
             length++;
            memcpy(p+1, "HOLA", 4);
   } } while (!(p==NULL));
   puts(strin);
}
```

If it detects the word  `HEY`  (with 1 whitespace between 2 sides) it should replace it with HOLA. Okay the issue is whenever I execute the software ;

Input : hello HEY Hi

Output : hello HOLA Hi#

A random character pops up everytime which I couldn't understand why . My object is is to change a word with another word .
Also my another question , how to exactly detect the existence of the word ? as HEY can be written in many ways same as Hey or HeY ect.

Comment: strcasestr() is like strstr() but ignores case

Comment: You're getting a "random" character because you haven't zero'd out the memory you allocate on the stack for `strin`. Also, you're calling `strlen()` on a variable which doesn't exist (how did this compile?)

Comment: If your input string is as long as you've allocated space for, then you're going to have problems when you overwrite HEY with HOLA because you're going to exceed the space for `strin`. btw, use `calloc()` to allocate zero'd out memory.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson it's not i even wrote a string with 10 caracs length and still have the issue

Comment: Yes, this will be the allocation problem. Before you use `strin` you have to zero it out, so call `memset(strin, '\0', 100);`. Two other things - what is `ch` supposed to be, and what does your for loop *actually* do? (Write out what each iteration is supposed to do, and see whether it really does. It's at this point that single-stepping through with a debugger is going to help you see what's really going on

Comment: @JamesMcPherson is deleted i mistakely typed it  also `memset(strin, '\0', 100);` makes my code crash in excute. I'm pretty sure the issue is in DO WHILE but idk where :(

Comment: This is where you use a debugger. If you're in an IDE, then you should be able to find a menu option to Debug your program; attach a breakpoint to the start of your `do...while` loop, and look at all your variables as you step. If you don't have an IDE then you should install + use `gdb` the GNU Debugger

Comment: "My code doesn't seem to perfect ... " -- nobody is! But I would start with fixing the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Need to move the null terminator forward with the rest.

```
for (p1=strin+length;p1>=p+4;p1--)
         *(p1+1) = *(p1);
```

By making this change we start by copying the null terminator rather than the last input character.

Soon you will need to change this code to do dynamic memory allocation.